# does librosa mfcc has a frequency selection API

Tags: audio, mfcc

Is there a API that allow me select frequency band that pass to MFCC algorithm?

say I have 2 different microphone, each have different frequency range, one 0~12000Hz, another 0~20000Hz
obviously, the FFT of result of first and second will be very different even when they are recording to save sound source.
For example, we set n_component 13, we have a low frequency source(10Hz) and a medium source(6000Hz), the first will have a FFT that high light at index 0 and 6, the second's high light will be located at 0 and 3.

The result vectors of MFCC will have large Euclidian distance that they shouldn't have.

If I can select frequency ceiling, frequency above 10000Hz can be cut off after FFT results calculated.
Then the MFCC vectors will be more likely close.

If there is a way or some tweak can achieve this please let me know.  (lowpass filter won't work on this case)

Many many thanks!

below is the difference showed by spectrogram (same sound source different microphone)

[image: diff]

Answer (score 2):

Brian answered my question on Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/librosa/fR0Kf-la8YU

> To solve this, simply pass a 'fmax' parameter to mfcc function like
>   this:
>
> ```
> mfcc(y=sig, sr=rate, n_mfcc=n_mfcc, fmax=fmax)
> ```